# In Matlab: How can one convert strings to use as a vector/matrix?

Tags: string, matlab, vector, char

How can one convert strings to use as a vector/matrix? 
For example, if the string is "Option 3"(Type=Char), and I have a vector to plot:

```
Time=1:100; 
Option3=3*Time; 
Option4=5*Time;
plot(Time,Output) %Where the output=Option 3
```

How can this be done? This is why I wonder, and where I got the question:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35412-list-selection-dialog?s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: Do you want to extract the number from the string? E.g. get 3 if the string is 'Option3'?. You can do `number = str2double(regexp(str, '\d+', 'match', 'once'));`, assuming there is only one number in your string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are essentially trying to find a way to map a given string (i.e. `'Option 3'`) to a vector of data. There are a number of approaches you could take. Here are a few:

- Use a [`switch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement:

  ```
  switch Output
    case 'Option_3'
      plot(Time, 3*Time);
    case 'Option _4'
      plot(Time, 5*Time);
  end
  ```

  Notice I put the `3*Time` *in* the switch case instead of computing it first as `Option3` and then using that variable in the call to `plot`. This saves memory since it doesn't create the data for each option until it is needed for plotting. If your variables (`Option3`, etc.) *have* to all be created first, just replace them accordingly in the switch statement.
- Create a [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) object:

  You can put all your vectors in a map with their corresponding option string, then use the option string to access and plot each vector:

  ```
  optionMap = containers.Map({'Option 3', 'Option 4'}, {3*Time, 5*Time});
  ...
  Output = 'Option 3';
  plot(Time, optionMap(Output));
  ```

  This will obviously require pre-computing all your vector data to put in the map. You could also do this yourself without a `containers.Map` object, such as with [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

  ```
  options = {'Option 3', 'Option 4'};  % Cell array of possible option strings
  vectorData = {3*Time, 5*Time};       % Cell array of corresponding vectors
  ...
  Output = 'Option 3';
  plot(Time, vectorData{strcmp(options, Output)});
  ```
- Use [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

  A [horrible](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) [decision](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56124-eval-is-evil-using-variables-created-dynamically-info-retrieval), [really](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval). But an option nonetheless. It requires that your `Output` string and your variables names are related in some way (in this case, removing the space from `Output` gives you your variable name):

  ```
  Output = 'Option 3';
  plot(Time, eval(strrep(Output, ' ', '')));  % Assumes Option3 variable exists
  ```

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion the easiest way to do what it seems like you wish to accomplish is an if statement.

```
if ( return == 'Option 3')
    y = 3*Time;
end
plot(Time, y);
```

And so on for your other options

Comment: That `if` statement is incorrect.  MATLAB does not compare strings that way.  Use `strcmpi` instead.

Comment: Also, `return` is a reserved keyword. Trying to use it in an `if` statement like that, or even trying to assign a value to a variable with that name, will result in a syntax error.